# php ftp upload is not sending a xml file

Tags: php, ftp

I have php code that generates an xml file from two database tables and saves the xml file to a directory in a website folder structure. The xml files are getting save correctly. After the file is saved it needs to be sent by ftp to an external ftp server folder.

```
function send_ftp($source_file, $destination_file)
{
// set up basic connection
$ftp_server = 'svr02.xxxxxxx.com';
$connection_id = ftp_connect('svr02.xxxxxxx.com'); 

// login with username and password
$ftp_user_name = 'xxxxx';
$ftp_user_pass = 'xxxxx';
$login_result = ftp_login($connection_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 
ftp_pasv($connection_id, true);

// upload the file
$upload = ftp_put($connection_id, $destination_file, $source_file, 
FTP_ASCII); 

// close the FTP stream 
ftp_close($conn_id); 
}
```

The connection seems to be fine and I can also use the same connection and credentials in FileZilla to manually upload the xml file.

How can I track down what the problem is, and am I using the ftp_put method correctly?

Thanks for any help..

**UPDATE 5/22/2017**
I added a function to return a var_dump as content I can use in a string or email etc.

```
function var_dump_ret($mixed = null) {
  ob_start();
  var_dump($mixed);
  $content = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  return $content;
}
```

With that code, then I can get the var dump output

```
$login_result = @ftp_login($connection_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 
$dump_content = var_dump_ret(var_dump($login_result));
send_to_dev('ftp login result', $dump_content);
```

The var_dump for login result is 'null' even though it should be true or false. I don't think I am getting a good login at this point.

**UPDATE 5/23/2017**
Per advice I change to using var_export function to get my variables. ftp_connect is failing; returning false, so the code is not even opening an ftp stream. I know that an ftp server is not to have 'ftp://' in front of it, and I cannot think of anything else. This ftp code is running on shared hosting on GoDaddy. Do you think there is a problem with GoDaddy blocking it?

Comment: try dumping `var_dump($connection_id, $destination_file, $source_file)` before the put command to make sure all the parameter are correct. also what is the value of `$upload` after you run it ?

Comment: Have you tried in binary mode? most ftp clients I think default to binary, yet you have FTP_ASCII.

Comment: `Also ftp_close($conn_id);` should be `ftp_close($connection_id);` Not that it will make much difference to your problem

Comment: What does `var_dump($upload)` show? Does `ftp_put` issue any PHP warning? What is format of the `$destination_file`?

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: [`var_dump`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) does not return anything, it's `void` function. You can use [`var_export($login_result, true)`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) instead + You didn't answer my other questions.

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for your help. I was trying to get the var dump to occur behind the scene so that I can gather data from the live web app. I can further answer your questions when I see the var dump. I will try var_export instead. This app is a live fire department dispatch system, and I need a call to be dispatched in order to get the variables.

Comment: Hi Martin, I updated the post with more info. var_export worked but exposed that ftp is not even creating a stream...

Comment: What if you dump `$connection_id`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I did, it returns 'false'

Comment: Than it indeed looks like the outgoing connection is blocked. What does `error_get_last` return after `ftp_connect`? + You should check with GoDaddy.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - thanks, I will get that error msg. I am on a call with GoDaddy now. I will update shortly.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl GoDaddy blocks these outbound connections of shared servers.

Answer (score 1):

Godaddy shared server hosting blocks outbound connections for security purposes. That is why ftp_connect would not open a connection.